# How to sort dictionary on second element of the key (tuple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I have a table as follows:-

```
table = {
        ('A', 10): 'student1',
        ('B', 12): 'student4', 
        ('C', 11): 'student3', 
        ('D', 11): 'student2',
        ('E', 9): 'student5'
        }
```

I want to sort(need not be in-place) this table by the second item of the tuple.

Expected output:-

```
table = {
        ('E', 9): 'student5'
        ('A', 10): 'student1',
        ('C', 11): 'student3', 
        ('D', 11): 'student2',
        ('B', 12): 'student4', 
        }
```

Comment: `dict(sorted(table.items(), key=lambda item: item[0][1]))`

Answer (score 5):

Recreate the dictionary from the `items()` tuple list of the original after sorting:

```
table = {
    ('A', 10): 'student1',
    ('B', 12): 'student4',
    ('C', 11): 'student3',
    ('D', 11): 'student2',
    ('E', 9): 'student5'
}
table = dict(sorted(table.items(), key=lambda x: x[0][1]))

print(table)
```

Result:

```
{('E', 9): 'student5', ('A', 10): 'student1', ('C', 11): 'student3', ('D', 11): 'student2', ('B', 12): 'student4'}
```